# regex to match IP address with 'x' in the ip address subnet

Tags: javascript, regex

currently we have regex

```
'/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/'
```

It is matches proper ip address but our requirement is to match for following formats

- 123.23.10.x.
- 123.23.x.x.
- 123.x.x.x

so it has to accept only a number or 'x' in the ip

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: [`^(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(?:(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|x)\.){2}(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|x)$`](https://regex101.com/r/ATGKM2/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `|x` inside your optional classes, you can add the possibility to match `x`s :

```
^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|x)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|x)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|x)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|x)$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gj4Y1h/1/).

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm off-topic but you could avoid regular expressions, I believe it's less error prone :

```js
var ips = [
  "0.0.0.0",
  "0.0.255.0",
  "123.x.x.x",
  "123.y.x.x",
  "0.0.256.0",
  "0.0.-1.0"
];

for (let i = 0; i < ips.length; i++) {
  console.log(validateIp(ips[i]) ? "pass" : "fail", ips[i]);
}

function validateIp (ip) {
  var strings = ip.split(".");
  if (strings.length != 4) return false;
  for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    let octet = parseInt(strings[i], 10);
    if (isNaN(octet) && strings[i] !== "x") {
      return false;
    } else if (octet < 0 || octet > 255) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is off-topic. This is written in the language that the OP specified and, in my opinion, is a better alternative to using regex. Regex is fantastic and all, but maintaining a regex can be a pain; especially when it's as long as this question requires.